# Sort on datagrid also sort null values in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid

Today i am getting some weird issue in datagrid.

```
<s:DataGrid id="grid_result" dataProvider="{somelist}" sortableColumns="true">
```

I have datagrid and on top header click it sort the column suppose this is the column.

```
<s:GridColumn headerText="Temp" dataField="tempName">
```

It will display tempName from someList. But some of data is null. So, when i sort this column on header of this column click it will sort null value also.

like it display:

```
A
B
.
.
l
m
blank cell
blank cell
o
p
.
.
Z
```

It consider null value after m and before o. I think it consider null as n(I may wrong for this).

I want to display null value at last. I have search lot but not found any solution.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create custom `sortCompareFunction` and force using `SortingCollator` class, which is supposed to handle `null` values.

```
private var collator:SortingCollator = new SortingCollator();

private function sortCompareFunction(obj1:Object, obj2:Object, gc:GridColumn):int {
    return collator.compare(obj1[gc.dataField], obj2[gc.dataField]);
}
```

And then assign it to the `GridColumn`.

```
<s:GridColumn headerText="Temp" dataField="tempName" sortCompareFunction="sortCompareFunction">
```

Comment: Thanks, working as expected. But can you tell me how it will sort null and put at and of the list?

Comment: When you look into the code, you find out that `SortingCollator` ends up using `ObjectUtils.stringCompare`, which handles the `null` problem: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/ObjectUtil.html#stringCompare()